# Cannot see table in Object Explorer, SQL Server 2005/2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

This may be a dumb question. But I just received permissions to read/write to this DB. I see the tables of the DB, except for one. I can select from it, But I cannot see it in the Object Explorer. I restarted my computer, refreshed the object explorer and everything. Is there a restriction on viewing this table?

---

I"m so sorry I had to check the connection of the query. I was looking at two different versions of the same DATABASE. gosh. Should I take this question down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query

```
SELECT type, type_desc FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'my_table_name'
```

should tell you what type of object your table *really* is.

Comment: thanks i used that and realized that the table didn't exist in the database I was looking at.. someone should have told me the difference between test and production...

Answer (score 2):

Could it be a synonym, or a view?  Check under the synonyms node and the views node.  Also check the schema... if you are just saying SELECT * FROM table, try with SELECT * FROM dbo.table.  It may be under a different schema.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the schema name in your create table query(eg. dbo.table name). By default it is getting created under your local server and hence it is available for you when you use the select query but once you check on server ita is not available.

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails, right click on Tables and click Refresh.